# jquery click without being attached to the DOM

Tags: jquery

```
var html = '<div><a href="#" id="test">Btn</a></div>';
$(html).find("#test").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});
//later
$(htmlNode).html(html);
```

Why don't I receive the "clicked" log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the jQuery object, rather than just setting the inner HTML:

```
var html = $('<div><a href="#" id="test">Btn</a></div>');
html.find("#test").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});
//later
$(htmlNode).append(html);
```

**EDIT**: Use `append` instead of `html` to be more clear, even though `html` seems to functionally equivalent to `.empty().append(val)` when passing in a jQuery object.

Comment: I believe this to be equivalent to what he has already.  You've merely defined html to be a jQuery object rather than the HTML.  He has your first line on his second line with `$(html)`.  Further, you set the html value to `html`, which won't work as you've defined `html` to be a jQuery object.

Comment: @Adam @jimy Huh? It works. Try it. Setting `html` to be a jQuery object instead of a string makes all the difference.

Comment: By golly, it does.  Never seen anyone use `html()` to effectively do what `append()` does.  Any functional difference between doing that vs a `empty()` and then `append()`?

Comment: If you look at the `html()` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/html/) there isn't even a function definition (that I'm seeing) that takes a jQuery object!  It's: `.html( htmlString )`.  You've found an undocumented feature! :)

Comment: @Adam Using `html` instead of `append` was somewhat unintentional :) (just a paste artifact). But in looking at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js, if the `html` arg isn't a string or function, it falls back to `this.empty().append( value );` (line 5263).

Comment: That's very interesting.  I have no choice but to say "I don't recommend this," simply because it's wholly undocumented, but yeah--very interesting.  Thanks for the research on that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're binding a click event to something that isn't in the DOM yet and isn't a jQuery object.  You can take two approaches.

1) Use Live:

```
$("#test").live('click', function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});
//later
var html = '<div><a href="#" id="test">Btn</a></div>';
$(htmlNode).html(html);
```

2) Construct a proper jQuery DOM object, and bind to that.

```
var a = $('<a></a>').attr('href', '#').click(function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
//later
$(htmlNode).html(a.wrap('<div></div>').html()); //This could also use append or appendTo.
```

The best approach depends on your situation.  Be sure to consider that appends to the DOM are very expensive in JavaScript!

Comment: He's trying to 1) create a DOM element, then 2) attach an event to it (in that order), so `live` is uncalled for.

Comment: For all you know his example was merely illustrative, as is mine.  `Live` is a perfectly appropriate solution to binding events to DOM elements that don't exist but will later.  All he needs to do is reorder his code.  And even if the order were some how relevant, I also provided option #2.  But generally yes, it's not _necessary_ to do `Live` in cases where you have control over the HTML as he seems to.  But, again, for all you know that html string he has is coming from a service, in which case using `Live` is more than "called" for.

Answer (score 0):

you are only attaching the click event to the html..you are not actually firing off the click event

try calling `.click()` after you attach the event.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume he's attempting to click on the anchor that was added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(htmlNode).html(html).filter("#test").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

Or you can do:

```
$("#test").live('click',function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

And create your html later

Answer (score 0):

Like above you are trying to add a click event to  a dom element that doesn't yet exist.

$.live is an ok option but unfortunately a pain to maintain in large applications and is rather slow.

You can wrap the event binding in a timeout which pushes the event binding to the end of the queue - which means the event biding will execute AFTER you push your new elements to the dom. Like this:

```
var html = '<div><a href="#" id="test">Btn</a></div>';
setTimeout(function(){$("#test").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});},0);
//later
$(htmlNode).html(html);
```